# Not able to pass value in post request Angular 6 Form group

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, api

This angular app making http.post request, I pass body for this API through form-group.Here is the code snippet

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab  label="New Account">
  <br><br>
  <button class="btn" type="button" (click)="saveRecord()" [disabled]="!recordForm.form.valid">Create</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <form  #recordForm="ngForm">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="name">Customer Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" [(ngModel)]="record.accountid" name="accountid" required>
 </div>
```

I am passing accountid to function(saveRecord), on click on button as shown above

I see record variable doesn't have any value though it is passed from formgroup

```
saveRecord() {
    console.log(this.record);// nothing is printed
    this.spinner.show();
    console.log(this.record);
    this.http.post('/api/accounts', this.record)
      .subscribe(res => {
     //status success or failure
   })
```

API fails to return as record ( req body is undefined )

Comment: did u initialise the record,  `record = {id:null}`

Comment: can you share more component code? like what have you initialized this.record with?

Comment: looks like `this.record` is null or undefined, do you set it somewhere?

Comment: Inside  nginit    ngOnInit() {  this.record = []; }

Comment: that won't work. it needs to be initialized like `this.record = {accountid: ""}`

Comment: Its working now I initialized record to record = {id:null}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added this in your component file

```
record = {
  accountid: null
};
```

otherwise, it will show an undefined error

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML

```
<button class="btn" type="button" (click)="saveRecord(recordForm)" [disabled]="!recordForm.form.valid">Create</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <form  #recordForm="ngForm">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="name">Customer Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" [(ngModel)]="record.id" name="accountid" required>
 </div>
 </form>
```

in your ts file

```
record = {id:null};

saveRecord(form:NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it will helps you.
HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="name">Customer 
         Number</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" 
           formControlName="accountid" required>
     </div>
     <button type="button"  class="btn" 
     (click)="saveRecord(recordForm)"
     [disabled]="recordForm.invalid">Create</button>
</form>
```

TS

```
   this.recordForm = new FormGroup({
      accountid: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });

    saveRecord(data) {
    console.log(data.value);// nothing is printed
    this.spinner.show();
    console.log(data.value);
    this.http.post('/api/accounts', data.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
     //status success or failure
   })
```